# order by using join in php

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Products and Userproducts.
Products table having columns:
id,name,description
and Userproducts table have following columns id,user_id,product_id.
Current query is

```
SELECT Products.id,Userproducts.user_id
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN UserProducts ON Productsid = Userproducts.product_id;
```

Now i want to show those products at the top whose users_id = 1 and other products will come after users products

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional order by clause as

```
SELECT p.id,u.user_id 
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN UserProducts u ON p.id = u.product_id
ORDER BY u.user_id = 1 desc, u.user_id asc
```

Comment: but without "=1", no condition here.

Comment: @Edward Without having condition how would your query know which records to show first and then other records, as this clause is mentioned in OP

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid Yes, you are right. But other records will be unsorted.